# Saving data into file at free host

Tags: c++

I have created an app (some kind of "client" app) that will have a "bug report" feature. The feature consists with pure text area from which the text should be sent and saved to a text file on the free host. Is it possible? If so, which c++ library could give me such ability?

EDIT:

In my intentions it had to be a simple application that a user has on his own computer. After finding some bug in my app there should be the "bug report" feature that will allow him to send the data (pure text) to some place that only I could reach. I was just thinking about free hosting (because it's... free), and save the data into a text file there. I'm sorry if my question wasn't appropriate.

Comment: you're missing details try to explane more  
is it an app that runs on the server or is it a web site?  
if so what web language are you using?

Comment: Do you understand the basics of HTTP ?

Comment: Is your application free software? What kind of application is it??

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Why does it matter? I just want to make a user able to inform me about bugs in my desktop c++ program. That's all I need.

Comment: Because for a free software, you already can find freely all the needed framework. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your free hosting permits it (and you should check that) you might code a [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) program, or a [fastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastcgi) application. There are several C++ libraries which might help, like [libcgicc](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++CGI.html) etc.

If you can afford a web server, there exist C++ libraries providing [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) service, in particular [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or (in C) [Onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion) etc.

You could also consider other technologies, like [OpaLang](http://opalang.org/) or [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/) (but I would not recommend PHP, even if it is a lot used).

MAybe your hosting enable `ssh` so you could use `scp` ....

And if your application is free software (e.g. GPL licensed), several free software hosting ([freecode](http://freecode.com/), [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/), [github](http://github.com/), [gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) ...) may offer also a bug database facility.